# Dynamic generated form with event keyup each separate actions

Tags: jquery

Well, I have a form and want to generate new forms equal starting from a parent form, and wish that each of these forms display what is typed on the form forward in a `p`, but when I do that the event propagates to all elements was dynamically generated. I just wanted it to propagate the corresponding form.

I am currently using the following code:

JS

```
jQuery(function(){
$(document).on('keyup','#il',function(){
$('p').append($(this).val());
})
$(document).on('click', '#btn',function(){
$("#in").append('<form>
<input id="il" type="text" size="20%">
<button id="btn" type="button">ADD</button>
<p></p><br />
</form>');
});
})
```

HTM

```
<div id="in">
<form>
<input id="il" type="text" size="20%">
<button id="btn" type="button">ADD</button>
<p></p><br />
</form>
</div>
```

**[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/opehuh/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not related to propagation of the event, you are selecting all the `p` elements, change:

```
$('p').append($(this).val());
```

To:

```
$(this).siblings('p').text(this.value);
```

http://jsbin.com/opehuh/7/edit

Note that you are generating invalid markup, IDs must be unique.